# ReactJS variable update without the code to be executed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm getting out of my mind...
If someone can explain this to me:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
        let categoriesChange = false

        console.log('check', JSON.stringify(this.checkedd), JSON.stringify(this.props.checked))

        if (JSON.stringify(this.checkedd) !== JSON.stringify(this.props.checked)) {
            console.log('did')

            categoriesChange = true

            this.checkedd = this.props.checked
            console.log('didit', JSON.stringify(this.checkedd), JSON.stringify(this.props.checked))
        }

        let currentQuery = this.returnQueryString(prevProps.filter);
        let nextQuery = this.returnQueryString(this.props.filter);

        if (categoriesChange) {
            if (nextQuery.send) {
                this.props.refresh(nextQuery.queryString);
            }
        }
    }
```

In this piece of code, the variable this.checkedd, which is instantiated with null in constructor, updates without entering in the JSON.stringify if.

Whenever Checked props(this.props.checked) is updated, the first console log shows them equal without entering in the if to show the "did" console.log.

[image: console log on different props change]

Can someone explain how is this even possible? that a variable updates without the piece of code to be executed?

Comment: When you set the value try this `this.checkedd = Object.assign({}, this.props.checked);` .I think probably your reference is causing issue. If not resolved try `this.checkedd = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.props.checked));`

Answer (score 0):

That's because objects are reference types in javascript. When you say, `this.checkedd = this.props.checked`, you are assigning the reference of the `this.props.checked` object to `this.checkedd` and not the actual value.

So when `this.props.checked` gets updated, `this.checked` will also reflect that change since they are both referring to the same object in memory.

Also, the way you are trying to achieve what you want is quite weird. You don't need to store the previous props value in an instance variable, i.e. `this.checkedd`. The `componentDidUpdate` hook has two parameters to it, `prevProps` and `prevState`. You could just check if the categories have changed by comparing the values in `prevProps.checked` and `this.props.checked`.